# How could force fields be stopped?

Tags: magic, physics, medieval, environment

My fantasy world has magic. Magic you are born with, and magic that can be learned. The mechanics of the force field the main characters are trapped in is that when you go in you can't leave. You are stuck there until the force field is shut down. There is one magic using character on the outside. What would be a good way to break this force field?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding!  As it stands, your question cannot be reasonably answered.  You've told us that under the rules of magic in your world, force fields are one-directional and cannot be broken until they shut down.  If those are the rules, then the answer is "they can't be".  If those _aren't_ the rules, then you haven't given us enough information to present an answer.  Either way, this question must be expanded before it can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options depending on the tone you want to set.

1. **Attack the source**.  If the force field is being created by a person or object, disrupting or destroying the person or object creating the field could destroy the field.
2. **Attack the field**.  The field might be vulnerable from the outside to magical or kinetic attacks.  Fireballs, beating on it with a hammer, force beams.
3. **A counter spell**. If there is a spell to make forcefields there should be a spell to unmake them.
4. **Lockpick solutions**. Forcefields are subtle woven things that can be picked apart by diligent study of them and application of the appropriate magics in the appropriate places.
5. **Locally abolishing magic**.  There is a way to destroy magic in an area either permanently or temporarily.
6. **Another Forcefield**.  Another forcefield inside the first will irresistibly expand until the first one breaks.  Alternatively a forcefield with the opposite orientation can be aligned with the first to negate it.